# Frameworks, libraries or tools for natural text processing in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, text-processing, text-parsing

I'm looking for a solution to extract dates from the user input. It should support:

- other languages than English
- it should be written in C/ObjC/C++/Python/Perl/Ruby
- the target platform is Mac OS X 10.6+
- it must not require internet connection

Paid solution are welcome as well as open source (non GPL).

Answer (score 2):

Apple included [NSDataDetector](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDataDetector_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in 10.7.
Besides URLs, phone numbers, etc. it also supports date (NSTextCheckingTypeDate) detection. (It seems that Mail.app makes extensive use of those detectors)

This example detects all dates in "string" and logs the matches (if any) locations & length:

```
NSError* error = NULL;
NSDataDetector* detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeDate error:&error];
NSArray* matches = [detector matchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
for (NSTextCheckingResult* match in matches) 
{
    NSRange matchRange = [match range];
    NSLog(@"Match at position:%lu with length:%lu", matchRange.location, matchRange.length);
}
```

Comment: Good answer (and +1 to you for that), but Kentzo is looking for a solution that runs under 10.6, too.

Comment: Thanks, missed it. But I still need to extract dates in 10.6 too, is there more naive solution (e.g. based on NSScanner or NSDateFormatter)?